# How do we represent a vector (or a point) in spherical coordinates (if its given in cartesian coordinates)?

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, vectors, geometry

Its easy to locate points and vectors cartesian coordinates using the good old,

3i+4j+5k

which says go 3m in direction of i, and j and k.
This might represent the direction some force acting on something at origin.

But, how would I represet this force in spherical coordinates?

Is there an equivalent expression in spherical coordinates as in catesian coordinates, which tells about the posion of a point, or a vector?

For eg. How would I represent these 2 points in spherical coordinates?
[image]

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system have you tried the conversions listed in this article?

Comment: I have used them, but im very confused about the results im getting

Comment: And what results are those?

Answer (score 2):

A position vector in the spherical coordinate system is written in form of
\begin{equation}\vec{r} = r\hat{r}\end{equation}
here $r$ is the magnitude of the vector and $\hat{r}(\theta, \phi)$ is the direction of vector which is itself a function of $\theta$ and $\phi$ so the vectors you asked can be written in form

\begin{equation}\vec{r_1} = \sqrt{2}\times\hat{r}\left(\frac{\pi}{4},0\right),
\vec{r_2} = \sqrt{2}\times\hat{r}\left(-\frac{\pi}{4},0\right)\end{equation}